# Возвращение рандомного числа JS

Tags: javascript

допустим у нас есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую, появляется рандомное число, и.т.д, я бы хотел узнать, как при нажатии на вторую кнопку, возвращать предыдущее рандомное число, или такое невозможно???

Comment: что значит _предыдущее рандомное число_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно сохранять числа в массив, и с него брать "предыдущее значение". Возможно не лучший вариант, но в целом работает

```js
const next = document.querySelector('#next')
const prev = document.querySelector('#prev')
const res = document.querySelector('#res')

function randomInteger(min, max) {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  return Math.round(rand);
}

const history = []

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const n = randomInteger(1,100)
  history.push(n)
  res.textContent = n
})

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  res.textContent = history[history.length - 2] || 'prev value is missing'
})
```

```html
<button id='next'>next</button>
<button id='prev'>prev</button>
<p id='res'></p>
```

Comment: Ну если значение ровно одно, можно хранить его в переменной, а не накапливать в массиве) Или вместе с push делать shift()

Answer (score 1):

Вижу это так, кхм

```js
let history = [], // Тут будем хранить историю, где первый элемент всегда _текущий_
    historyLength = 1, // Длина истории - сколько записей может поместиться
    max = 1000, // Это макс. рандомное значение
    
    // это для элементов
    eRand = document.querySelector('#rand'),
    eLast = document.querySelector('#last'),
    eNum = document.querySelector('#num');
    
function Random() {
  history.unshift(Math.floor(Math.random() * max)); // unshift добавит значение в начало массива, значением является рандомное число от нуля до max
  history.length = historyLength+1; // Обрезаем массив до доступной длины (historyLength + ячейка под _текущее_ значение)
  eNum.innerText = 'Random: '+history[0]; // Вывод на экран _текущего_ значения
}

// Вещаем на кнопку #rand обработчик на клик, где будем выполнять функцию Random();
eRand.addEventListener('click', function(){
  Random();
});

// Тоже вешаем обработчик на клик, но уже на кнопку #last, где будем:
eLast.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(history[1]) // Если последний параметр существует, то:
    eNum.innerText += '\nLast: '+history[1]; // Выводим значение на экран.
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="rand" value="Random">
<input type="button" id="last" value="Last">
<div id="num"></div>
```

Comment: Вместо if и slice, можно сразу рубить `history.length = historyLength + 1;`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, спасибо, интересное решение, не знал о нём.

Answer (score 0):

Как пример

```js
var number = null;

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function KeyPress(e) {
  if (e.id == 'b1')
    number = getRandomInt(10);
  else
    alert(number);
}
```

```html
<button id="b1" onclick="KeyPress(this)">Кнопка 1</button>
<button id="b2" onclick="KeyPress(this)">Кнопка 2</button>
```